# How to make the first part of two syntactical equivalent parts optional when analysing with pyparsing

Tags: python, grammar, text-parsing, pyparsing

With the parsing library [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) I want to analyse constructs like this:

```
123 456

-^- -^-
[A]  B
```

where both parts **A** and **B** only contain numbers and part **A** is optional. Here some examples how a parser for this would break strings down in their parts:

```
123 456 ==> A="123", B="456"
456     ==> A="",    B="456"
123     ==> A="",    B="123"
1 123   ==> A="1",   B="123"
```

The native approach to write a parser looks like this:

```
a = pp.Optional(pp.Word(pp.nums)).setName("PART_A")
b = pp.Word(pp.nums).setName("PART_B")
expr = a('A')  + b('B')
```

This parser works for `"123 456"` returning as expected `{'A': '123', 'B': '456'}`. However it fails on `"456"` with:

```
ParseException:
Expected PART_B (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
"456>!<"
```

This is understandable because the optional part **A** already consumes the text which should match part **B** even though **A** was optional... My idea was to set a `stopOn=` option, but it needs to stop on an expression of the same type as the expression it wants to match...

**Update:** My 2nd idea was to re-write the `Optional` construct into a `Or` construct:

```
a = pp.Word(pp.nums).setName("PART_A")('A')
b = pp.Word(pp.nums).setName("PART_B")('B')
just_b = b
a_and_b = a + b
expr = pp.Or(just_b, a_and_b)
```

However, this now fails for texts of the form `"123 456"` - despite the fact that `a_and_b` is a alternative in the `Or` class...

Any suggestion what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misconstructing the Or, it should be:

```
expr = pp.Or([just_b, a_and_b])
```

The way you are constructing it, the Or is being built with just `just_b`, with `a_and_b` being passed as the boolean argument `savelist`.

Please consider using the operator overloads to construct And, Or, MatchFirst, and Each expressions.

```
integer = pp.Word(pp.nums)

a = integer("A")
b = integer("B")

expr = a + b | b
```

The explicit style looks just so, well, Java-ish.

To answer the question in your title, you pretty much have already solved this: be sure to try matching the full `a_and_b` expression, either by placing it first in a MatchFirst (as my sample code does), or by using an Or expression (using the '^' operator, or by constructing an Or using a list of the `just_b` and `a_and_b` expressions).

Comment: Works perfectly. What an oversight on my part: Or expects lists!

Comment: So, do I understand it correctly that the `Optional` class is not needed when using the `a + b | b` construct?

Comment: Correct, since you are explicitly describing the two allowed cases. A leading Optional by itself won't really work as you have discovered. If you wanted 'b' to be optional, you could do `a + b | a` or just `a + Optional(b)`. But as you have seen, a leading optional is not so simple. `Optional(a) + b` will fail on '456' because '456' will match the 'a', and then there will be no 'b'. We must make the parser think like we do. That is, we know a is present only if followed by b. So this should work if you want to use Optional: `expr = Optional(a + FollowedBy(b)) + b`.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the details. Makes sense.